# Update strategy for some CentOS packages

Tags: centos, package-management, php

We are a free/open source project. We rent a CentOS 7 x86_64 VM for a website and wiki. We keep the VM fully patched. Once a week we log-in and run `yum update` to ensure we have the latest gear.

Some packages are starting to give us trouble as the distro ages. For example, PHP version is 5.4, which went [End-of-Life in 2015](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php):

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2017 16:33:54)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
    with XCache Optimizer v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
    with XCache Cacher v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
    with XCache Coverager v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
```

The downlevel PHP means our matching MediaWiki software is no longer maintained. We are stuck at MediaWiki 1.26.

According to [highest PHP version supported on CentOS 7](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63687) one of the possibilities is enable a third party repo. I'm OK with enabling additional repos; but I don't like enabling a foreign one.

According to the [CentOS FAQ](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General?highlight=%28packages%29), CentOS is the Community Development Platform for the Red Hat built from Red Hat sources. I seriously doubt RHEL is only providing abandoned software to their customers.

According to the CentOS wiki on [Additional Resources | Repositories](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) there is a CentOS-Plus repo that can be enabled. I [checked the repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/centosplus/x86_64/Packages/) and there is no updated PHP available.

My first question is, why does CentOS *not* provide an updated PHP?

My second question is, do we always need to trust *<some random source>* when using CentOS?

My third question is, is there a workable strategy for part-time system admins that avoids third party repos?

Question (1) is the instance problem in our case. I suppose others have had the same problem with other CentOS software.

Question (2) is for long term planning. If CentOS is always going to cause this problem over time, then we need to evaluate if we should look for another distro.

Question (3) is mostly concerned with (a) up-to-date software and (b) trusted sources and repos. We are OK with extra configuration effort, but we would like to minimize it. We really want to avoid untrusted sources.

In the bigger picture I kind of feel like there is something [obvious] I am missing. But I don't know what that is at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

> My first question is, why does CentOS not provide an updated PHP?

This is a Red Hat decision. This is more than likely because of something they provide that relies on such an old version - but I cannot find evidence of this.

If you need a more up to date PHP, you have plenty of resources, such as [IUS](https://ius.io/FAQs/#php) or even the [SCL](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) that CentOS provides. IUS will not overwrite existing packages, but they will require you to remove whatever is there first, php wise. I use IUS for python 2.7 for CentOS 6 so I can install salt properly.

Note: Red Hat is ultimately who decides what packages and what versions go into their distribution, from a stability standpoint. CentOS merely takes the sources and rebuilds them into CentOS.

> Do we always need to trust *some random source* when using CentOS?

Not necessarily. There are plenty of good and bad repos out there. In fact, some people can easily live on just the base repositories.

It really depends on your needs. Go to [this page here](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) to see what repos are approved by the community. Rest assured, that any repo listed on that page is approved and **can be trusted**.

> is there a workable strategy for part-time system admins that avoids third party repos?

The best strategy depends on a user's or a company's use case is. For your particular use case, you are going to need third party repos. You really don't have a choice, especially if you cannot get MediaWiki to go to a higher version. As noted in the previous answer, some people can live with just base repos just fine. Some people just go as far as just using EPEL. Again, it depends on your use case and what you are running or maintaining. Rest assured, that anything that comes out of EPEL or IUS (for example) is typically as maintained, stable, and secure as what comes out of the base of the distribution.

I still recommend going [here](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) for community approved repos.

Comment: Thanks @Sokel. I thought CentOS was based on Red Hat but Cent was its own separate project. It sounds more like Red Hat is both projects. Forgive my ignorance... What is Red Hat doing? Are they _really_ supplying PHP 5.4, and then advising folks to go to some third party site to get updated packages? I'm baffled we cannot find something newer with established provenance from centos.org.

Comment: CentOS is a project - CentOS merely pulls all the sources from Red Hat and rebuilds them into CentOS. So everything is like for like. Red Hat simply advises that if a user wants a newer version of a software to use an SCL. Before they never offered such and left everyone to their own devices. This is why IUS and others were born. Again, CentOS has an SCL that provides newer versions of packages. Please go to the links in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Some packages are starting to give us trouble as the distro ages. For example, PHP version is 5.4, which went End-of-Life in 2015

Yes, but security patches are [backported](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting). The only real reason to upgrade to a newer version of PHP is for the language features or if an application needs it, but you miss out on security (or other distro-specific) patches this way.

> We are a free/open source project. We rent a CentOS 7 x86_64 VM for a website and wiki. We keep the VM fully patched.

Is this really necessary? The cheap solution would be to host a website using Github Pages and use either Github for the wiki or use a static web page generator like Sphinx. If you want to go one step further, you can use Cloudflare and point it towards your GH pages site. See the answers to [Hack-resistant hosting solution for non-profit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/116877) for additional information on this.

Advantages:

- Completely free
- Simpler language (Markdown/restructured text) instead of MediaWiki syntax
- Simpler maintenance, since you don't need to deal with any server-side stuff
- Lower barrier of entry since this is a solution already used by many open-source projects, i.e readthedocs.org and browse Github for plenty of examples
- Not running server-side technologies drastically reduce the attack surface. Attackers would need to exploit Github Pages and Cloudflare offers plenty of protection, whereas you would need to do all the hard work of hardening your VM if you DIY

Comment: GitHub cannot be used for a wiki because it has an unusual permission model. It was a bad fit for wikis and collaboration. Effectively we needed another repo for wiki that was world writeable. Plus we had a 15 year old wiki and we were not sure about the migration. After evaluating it we decided against it.